# Recurrence T(n) = T(n - log(n)) + 1

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

How do you find the tight-bound for a such recurrence relation? This is a hw question and we are expected to prove that m/log(m) is the tight asymptotic bound. I tried using induction but it seems to go nowhere. It is either I am missing something with logarithm rules or there is something more to it.

Comment: Show us how you start the induction, maybe someone can help you from there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a programming question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Induction. Assume `T(k) <= C k / log k` for some `C` for all `k < n`.

Unroll the recurrence `(n/2) / log(n/2)` times, replacing `log(.)` with `log(n/2)` (we exploit the fact that both `T(n)` and `log(n)` are monotone function). That is,

`T(n) <= T(n - log(n/2) * (n/2) / log(n/2)) + (n/2) / log(n/2)`

`T(n) <= T(n/2) + (n/2) / log(n/2)`

`T(n) <= C (n/2) / log(n/2) + (n/2) / log(n/2)`

Now you have to prove that the expression on the right is bounded by `C n / log n`. Arithmetics and finding such `C` is left as an exercise.

Comment: I do not agree. I think solution should be in form :
`(n-log(n)) / (log(n - log(n)))`

Comment: @nomadov It depends on the level of approximation you need.

Comment: How do you unroll the recurrence `(n/2) / log(n/2)` times? I did not understand how you obtained `T(n) <= T(n - log(n/2) * (n/2) / log(n/2)) + (n/2) / log(n/2)`

Comment: Maybe a more detailed explanation would be much better and helpful